# Weird: Text disappears on rotation

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a map application where booth numbers are being auto-generated for the booths.

In the map controls, you can rotate the map 90 degrees and when the map is at 0 degrees of rotation, the booth numbers show up just fine.  However, at -90, -180 and 90 the text is gone.

Here's the map
http://build.map-dynamics.com/dev

Here's the function used to generate the text fields:

```
function addTextField(childObj, textValue){
    var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
    myTextField.text = textValue;
    var myRectangle = childObj.getBounds(childObj);

    myTextField.width = (childObj.width/childObj.scaleX);
    myTextField.x = 0+myRectangle.x;
    myTextField.y = 0+myRectangle.y + (myRectangle.height/2)-6;
    myTextField.mouseEnabled = false;

    myTextField.selectable = false;  
    myTextField.border = false; 
    myTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;    
    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
    myFormat.color = 0x000000;  
    myFormat.size = (text_size / childObj.scaleX);  
    myFormat.font = "Arial";

    myTextField.setTextFormat(myFormat);    
    childObj.addChildAt(myTextField,1);  
}
```

Even just some idea of where to start looking would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it means that the font is not embedded.

try embedding it (might take more than `myTextField.embedFont = true;`)

Comment: Maybe I did it wrong, but when I did that it got rid of all my labels.

Comment: it means that it can't find the font. Font embedding in as3 is an often discussed subject the problem is that it is different between different Flash versions and Flex. you can try googling for your version of IDE/compiler.

Comment: I found this line of code in the docs:
[Embed(source="C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\arial.ttf", fontFamily="arial")]

Comment: Looks like your answer is the correct one, I'm just need to find the correct libraries now.  Thanks for your help Daniel.

Comment: something like that for the flex compiler.  Have a look at http://mx.coldstorageonline.com/index.php?bid=48